# Rails 4 - Stripe Zipcode & Street Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm building a ecommerce app and am using Stripe. The payment system works but at this point, the only verification is the card number and cvc. I want to add zipcode and street validation.

I started with zip first and then will add the address line. I did the below:

I've checked off the zipcode validation box in my stripe account. Then, per the [Stripe doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-avs), I need to use the attribute "address_zip" to pass the zip to stripe. The below is part of the order form.

```
<%= f.text_field :zip, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "address_zip", class: "form-control" } %>
```

When I place an order, I get an error no matter what zip  I enter. Even the correct zip gives me an error. But the error is a model validation error saying that "Zip cannot be blank". This is not a stripe error.

I based the above line of code based on the cvc code as below. This works.

```
<%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc", class: "form-control" } %>
```

Why is my zip not being read? My old code was `<%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control" }` and it worked fine.

UPDATE:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
      false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
      $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks right at first glance. I wonder why your `address_zip` line is using `f.text_field` while the `cvc` line is using `text_field_tag`, though. The APIs for these methods are different, so I would check the actual rendered markup in the browser to make sure what you expect has been generated.

Failing that, could you paste your Stripe.js-based Javascript as well? Are you passing in the form element as the parameter to `createToken`?

Comment: I added the coffeescript to the post. I haven't tested it yet by changing the zip from f. to _tag. I'm saving the zip in my model so I'm not sure if it will save if I remove the 'f.'. The zip is part of the order form_for that gets saved in the model.

Comment: Did the markup look right in in the source of the page? Maybe paste what gets generated as well. The CoffeeScript looks fine. You might consider not passing in the form as the first argument to `createToken` but rather breaking out the values from the form yourself into an object so you can inspect them and make sure they're all there/etc.